# In "Friends", does any of the six wear the same clothes in different episodes?

Tags: friends

Does any of the six main characters in "Friends" ever appear in the same clothes in two or more different episodes? I am speaking about normal casual everyday clothes like shirts, t-shirts, skirts, dresses etc (jeans, tuxedos, suits excluded, because they look very similar).

PS. For obvious reasons, flashbacks are excluded too.

Comment: I think yes, One situation could be Ross wearing his Red jersey on the episode that Others knew it was Ross who is the dad of Rachel's baby, it shows he wearing the red jersey, meeting Tag. After that episode, we see flashback scene which Ross happens to be video taped.

Comment: @Vishwa It would be very strange if Ross had a different jersey in this very situation where that jersey was a central plot point :)

Comment: Obviously. but you did ask **does any of the six wear the same clothes in different episodes?**

Comment: @Vishwa Yes. I updated the question.

Comment: Just noticed one while rewatching the series again. In season 7, Rachel can be seen wearing the same sweater in episodes 7 and 13.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Biggest easiest to spot is Joey black Leather Jacket. It's seen in the first season "The guy says Hello And I want to kill myself", The one when Joey tries to have twin for a role "WE LIKE PIZZA" and last when Chandler and Monica are buying house "What, I'm not good enough for you?".

Also I would go on a limb and say that "Could I be wearing any more clothes?" count.

Comment: As far as I remember "Could I be wearing any more clothes?" is something Joey says while wearing a lot of Chandler's clothes, so not really any of the characters wearing clothes he/she has worn before/will wear later on in the series.

Answer (score 3):

While not being the same exact shirt(s), there are multiple instances in Season(s) 4/5 where Chandler wears the same style of shirt but with different colors. The first one that I notice is when he's depressed after breaking up with [Kathy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicu7.jpg). The shirt in question looks like this:

[image: ][1]]

Chandler wears this same shirt but with different colors multiple times throughout the season. I have counted Chandler wearing at least 5 of this kind of shirt.